# Batch file to remove text between 2 characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-manipulation

Is it possible to write a Windows batch file that can delete all text between 2 characters, including the characters themselves?

I am dynamically generating text files that includes a piece of text in HTML format. I want to extract only the non-HTML part of the text, meaning, I want to remove all HTML tags from it.

So, I want a Windows batch file that takes a text file as input, removes all characters between < and > (including) and creates an output file. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You would be better off using python

Comment: ... or JScript.  JScript can even parse the HTML as a [collection of DOM elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you wish.  Or it can do a `string.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'')` to strip all tags if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need this batch script to be given to the user. If it is a simple batch file, the user can just run that file and be done with it. If it is in Python or JScript, it will be more complex

Comment: [Incorrect](https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/5199433).  (I typically use the Hybrid2.bat style in my hybrid batch / JScript scripts.)